# Select extended properties of Roles

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, extended-properties

I'd like to get extended properties for database's roles. I can get a list of all extended properties for users with this command:

```
use db;
SELECT * FROM fn_listextendedproperty (null, 'user', null, default, default, default, default)
```

But I'm not able to find correct [level types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179853.aspx) for roles.

With using following command I can see that roles' `class` is 4 and their `major id` is 10.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.extended_properties
```

So I can get what I'm looking for with the below command:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.extended_properties WHERE class = 4 AND major_id = 10
```

But I prefer to get the list with `fn_listextendedproperty` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [sys.extended_properties (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177541(v=sql.90).aspx)

> **major_id**: ID of the item on which the extended property exists,
>   interpreted according to its class.

So `major_id = 10` is the `principal_id` of the role in `sys.database_principals`.

And `class = 4` is database principals, users and roles both.

Your first query that uses `fn_listextendedproperty` should return a list of both users and roles with the `obj_type = USER` for both types.

You need to use `sys.extended_properties` and join to `sys.database_principals` to figure out what is a user and what is a role.

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that `user` will returns roles too. But on what key I should join them? Properties' names aren't unique, some users might have similar property names too.